# Container registry not showing up in azure when creating a workload

Tags: azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I am trying to create a workload on AKS using the web portal.  I have done this successfully on my one AKS cluster. However I have made a new one, and it refuses to show me the available ACR (container registries)  which are certainly in the same subscription.

[image]

Is there something I have to do to physically link the two together?

Comment: There is a parameter called `--attach-acr` to link your cluster with ACR if it is not visible automatically. If you have already created a cluster then you can pass the parameter with [`az aks update --attach-acr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-update) command. @Zapnologica

Comment: Did you check the above approach? @Zapnologica

Answer (score 1):

> Container registry not showing up in azure when creating a workload:-

***Need to check below:***

- Check whether cluster and container registry are in the same subscription.
- Clear browser cache and try opening in different browser other than the current one.
- If you're using a service principal to access the AKS and ACR, make sure it has the proper privileges to retrieve the container registry details.

***I tried creating a workload on AKS and it shown up container registries available in my cluster environment.***

[image]

If still the issue persists, try below workaround to attach the `ACR` using `AzCLI` command as follows.

```bash
az aks update -g <resourcegroup> -n <clustername> --attach-acr <containerregistry>
```

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-update) for brief understanding on above given command.