# How to provide access of ACR to Azure container apps which are not in same network group?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry, azure-container-apps

I have ACR i.e., `myregistry` in `production-network-group` and I was creating container apps in `dev-network-group`, `uat-network-group` and `prod-network-group`.

Currently, I was trying to connect with `myregistry` from dev, uat networks using credentials as shown below,

[image]

How to use `Azure container Registry` as image source instead of `Docker Hub or other registries`? How to provide access of my ACR to all of the `dev` and `uat` container apps?

There is no issue for prod, I can use `Azure Container Registry` as image source as they both are in same network.

Any kind of workarounds to solve this issue are appreciable.

Comment: Is there a private endpoint associated with your ACR?

Comment: @simon-pearson No, there is no private endpoint and system assigned identity is also disabled in our ACR.

Comment: What is the error message that you get? Also in you picture you used azreAcr.io for registry server, that is wrong, the correct domain is azurecr.io without "a".

Comment: @zsolt I was not able to see my azure container registry when I selected `Azure container Registry` as image source instead of `Docker Hub or other registries`. That was typo, I was able to connect successfully, if I use `Docker Hub or other registries`. I want to remove dependency on credentials by selecting `Azure container Registry` but due network groups are different, it was not showing up. How to provide access?

Comment: You can set up a private endpoint in your ACR for each VNet. Private endpoints allow you to access the ACR via a private IP address directly from your VNet. Did you try in that way? @Pythoncoder

Comment: @Jahnavi No, I haven't tried that. Can you please steps to do this?

Comment: @Jahnavi And, also want to know, is there any way using managed identity to fix this issue?

Comment: You can do it by going to `Networking` under ACR. Choose selected networks and enable firewall by giving the required IP addresses. And then click on `allow access from trusted services` as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/LE12bfP.png). @Pythoncoder

Comment: Yes you can also use managed identity to fix it and it is detailed here in [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/container-instances/using-azure-container-registry-mi.md). @Pythoncoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to provide access of ACR to Azure container apps which are not in same network group: -

You can create Private endpoints which allow you to access the container registry directly from your virtual network using a private IP address.

*After a workaround on your issue, I found below approach to access ACR from other virtual networks.*

Goto `container registry` >> `Networking` >> Choose selected networks and enable firewall by adding which IP addresses to block (if required) >> Enable `allow access from trusted` >> Click on save.

[image]

Alternatively, you can create a identity to the ACR and add the required permissions to the specific managed identity as shown in [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/container-instances/using-azure-container-registry-mi.md).

I've created an identity and added permissions using `AzCLI`:

```bash
az identity create --resource-group <resourcegroup> --name newcrj
uid=$(az identity create --resource-group <resourcegroup> --name newcrj --query id --output tsv)
spid=$(az identity show --resource-group <resourcegroup> --name newcrj --query principalId --output tsv)
az role assignment create --assignee $spid --scope $uid --role acrpull
```

[image]

**Update:**

After a discussion and workaround on your issue, I found that there is no possibility of attaching ACR to the container app without using credentials if it is a private registry.

I tried with all the deployment methods and each deployment is prompting for user credentials for private registries.

Comment: I have enabled `allow access from trusted`, but it is still not showing up in image source `Azure Container Registry` to create a container app. And the provide MSDoc is deploying on container instances, but not container apps.

Comment: Is this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76859852/19785512) works for you? @Pythoncoder

Comment: I see that, it is attaching ACR to AKS cluster, I am using azure container apps, how to attach ACR to other network, to see my ACR while creating a new container app?

Comment: Can you try in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/network-rule?view=azure-cli-latest) way? @Pythoncoder

Comment: You can also use [az containerapp update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-update-examples) to link it with the ACR after creating a container app. @Pythoncoder

Comment: Do i need to link using credentials like username password?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255082/discussion-between-jahnavi-and-python-coder).